# Optmization for quicksort in x86 32-bit assembly

Tags: c, assembly, quicksort

I'm trying to learn some basic x86 32-bit assembly programming. So in pursuing this I decided to implement quicksort in assembly (sorting only integers). First I made a C-version of the sorting function and then I made an assembly version.

However, when comparing my assembly version with the my C-version (compiled with gcc on Debian), the C-version performs more then 10 times faster on a array of 10000 integers.

So my question is if anybody can give some feedback on obvious optimizations that can be made on my quick sort assembly routine. It's purely for educational purposes and I'm not expecting to beat the compiler makers in terms of producing high speed code but I'm interested in knowing if I'm making any obvious mistakes that hampers speed.

The C-version:

```
void myqsort(int* elems, int sidx, int eidx)
{

    if (sidx < eidx)
    {
        int pivot = elems[eidx];
        int i = sidx;
        for (int j = sidx; j < eidx; j++)
        {
            if (elems[j] <= pivot)
            {
                swap(&elems[i], &elems[j]);
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        swap(&elems[i], &elems[eidx]);
        myqsort(elems, sidx, i - 1);
        myqsort(elems, i + 1, eidx);
    }
}
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Assembly version (NASM):

```
;
; void asm_quick_sort(int* elems, int startindex, int endindex)
; Params:
;       elems - pointer to elements to sort - [ebp + 0x8]
;       sid - start index of items - [ebp + 0xC]
;       eid - end index of items - [ebp + 0x10]
asm_quick_sort:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push edi
    push esi
    push ebx

    mov eax, dword [ebp + 0xC]  ; store start index,  = i
    mov ebx, dword [ebp + 0x10] ; store end index
    mov esi, dword [ebp + 0x8]  ; store pointer to first element in esi

    cmp eax, ebx
    jnl qsort_done

    mov ecx, eax                        ; ecx = j, = sid
    mov edx, dword [esi + (0x4 * ebx)]  ; pivot element, elems[eid], edx = pivot
qsort_part_loop:
    ; for j = sid; j < eid; j++
    cmp ecx, ebx                    ; if ecx < end index
    jnb qsort_end_part
    ; if elems[j] <= pivot
    cmp edx, dword [esi + (0x4*ecx)]
    jb qsort_cont_loop
    ; do swap, elems[i], elems[j]
    push edx ; save pivot for now
    mov edx, dword [esi + (0x4*ecx)]        ; edx = elems[j]
    mov edi, dword [esi + (0x4*eax)]        ; edi = elems[i]
    mov dword [esi + (0x4*eax)], edx        ; elems[i] = elems[j]
    mov dword [esi + (0x4*ecx)], edi        ; elems[j] = elems[i]
    pop edx ; restore pivot
    ; i++
    add eax, 0x1
qsort_cont_loop:
    add ecx, 0x1
    jmp qsort_part_loop
qsort_end_part:
    ; do swap, elems[i], elems[eid]
    mov edx, dword [esi + (0x4*eax)]        ; edx = elems[i]
    mov edi, dword [esi + (0x4*ebx)]        ; edi = elems[eid]
    mov dword [esi + (0x4*ebx)], edx        ; elems[eidx] = elems[i]
    mov dword [esi + (0x4*eax)], edi        ; elems[i] = elems[eidx]

    ; qsort(elems, sid, i - 1)
    ; qsort(elems, i + 1, eid)
    sub eax, 0x1
    push eax
    push dword [ebp + 0xC]  ; push start idx
    push dword [ebp + 0x8]  ; push elems vector
    call asm_quick_sort
    add esp, 0x8
    pop eax
    add eax, 0x1
    push dword [ebp + 0x10] ; push end idx
    push eax
    push dword [ebp + 0x8]  ; push elems vector
    call asm_quick_sort
    add esp, 0xC


qsort_done:
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    ret
```

I call the assembly routine from C and I use clock() for timing the routines.

**EDIT**
The difference in performance is no longer an issue after correcting the bugs pointed out by my fellow stackoverflowers.

Comment: You could have the compiler output assembly code and compare the generated code to your code.

Comment: One thing that is immediately obvious is that the second recursive call to `mysort()` can be tail-call eliminated. Since you don't do this in your assembly-code, that's already a nice advantage for the compiler.

Comment: @rkhb - I added swap to my original post.

Comment: @EOF - Thanks for the tip, I will look into how to make use of tail recursion!

Comment: @pushebp you want to look into how to _eliminate_ tail recursion (you already _make use_ of it). Hint: instead of calling the function again (recursing), can you just jump back to (somewhere near) the start?

Comment: Also FWIW I get a segmentation fault when I try your assembly qsort routine - so it might be slower because it is _incorrect_.

Comment: I have described the problem with the bug in the assembly implementation in my answer below.

Comment: @davmac - Yes sorry my bad times 2. I have noticed the seg faults as well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your assembly sort implementation, and speed comparisons are useless until you resolve it. The problem is the recursive call:

```
    myqsort(elems, sidx, i - 1);
```

Seeing as it is not necessarily the case that `i` is not `sidx`, this might pass a value less than `sidx` to the function, including -1 if `sidx` is 0. This is handled in your C implementation:

```
if (sidx < eidx)
```

But in your assembly version:

```
cmp eax, ebx
jae qsort_done
```

That's an *unsigned* comparison branch instruction! You should be using `jge`. I see a segfault due to this problem. When fixed, the performance of both implementations appears to be roughly the same according to my quick tests (compiling with -O3). I used the following test driver:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void myqsort(int * elems, int sidx, int eidx);

#define SIZE 100000

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int * elems = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            elems[i] = rand();
        }

        myqsort(elems, 0, SIZE - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the C version, run-time was approx 5.854 seconds.
With the assembly version, it was 5.829 seconds (i.e. slightly faster).

Comment: @rhkb I can't make heads or tails of your comment. Yes, the `cmp` instruction compares the indices. No, the `jae` instruction doesn't work with negative indices. This is already explained above.

Comment: @rhkb Those statements will produce different results when one of the values being compared (`sidx`, `eidx`) happens to be negative (and the other is not).

Comment: @rhkb "If both are positive there is no effective difference between `jae` and `jge`" - I have explained, in my answer above, quite succinctly, how it is possible that the `sidx` value may be negative, in which case there is an important distinction between `jae` and `jge`. "Did you handle with a negative `sidx` or a negative `eidx`" - This question doesn't make sense to me. _I_ didn't handle nor fail to handle either of these cases. I have suggested to OP how to handle them. This suggestion is in my answer, which you can see for yourself, just above.

Comment: @rhkb I had a segfault when I ran the code via the driver that I have provided in my answer. I no longer see a segfault after I changed the `jae` to a `jge`. The segfault occurs due to an out-of-bounds memory access resulting from the treatment of a -1 index value as an 0xFFFFFFFF index value.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, you are correct, the error was with unsigned comparison at the beginning of the subroutine. But I wanted to find the source of the seg fault myself so my response took a while. I also realized when doing some more tests that the sorting didn't quite work correctly. This was an error in the parameters to the recursive calls, I will update my original post.
After correcting the errors the assembly routine did out perform my C-version.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the swapping of elements using only 1 additional register EDI and without the need for pushing and popping the pivot value in EDX:

```
mov  edi, dword [esi + (0x4*eax)]   ; edi = elems[i]
xchg dword [esi + (0x4*ecx)], edi   ; elems[j] = edi, edi = elems[j]
mov  dword [esi + (0x4*eax)], edi   ; elems[i] = edi
```

The second swap can also be shortened:

```
mov  edi, dword [esi + (0x4*ebx)]   ; edi = elems[eid]
xchg dword [esi + (0x4*eax)], edi   ; elems[i] = edi, edi = elems[i]
mov  dword [esi + (0x4*ebx)], edi   ; elems[eid] = edi
```

You can safely remove the `mov esp, ebp` from your epilog code because it is redundant. If those 3 `pop`'s went well you already know that the stackpointer has the correct value.

```
qsort_done:
  pop ebx
  pop esi
  pop edi
  mov esp, ebp    <-- This is useless!
  pop ebp
  ret
```

Comment: I tried using xchg as you described, however it did not improve the execution time of the subroutine.

Comment: @pushebp Even if using `xchg` did not improve the execution time it is still the more **elegant** solution. That should count for something!